# Xvnc multiscreen setup

Tags: vnc, multi-monitor

I have an old application that uses hardcoded screen names in a multimonitor setup. (8 bit indexed color). it if course does not recognize RandR or Xinemra, but uses both rhost:0.0 and rhost:0.1 for fullscreen windows (internal window manager). I would prefer Xvnc as I do not want to use a video card if I don't have to, but this is not a hard and fast requirement. Has anyone got something similar to work with? Which vnc did you use? How did you do it?